# roll back when creating a user in keycloak?

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

recently I am using keycloak as IAM tool, I use the java api to create a user on keycloak then I am sending message to verify that user, now wvwey thing is working but the problem is I want to do it as a transaction " whenever any exception raised during registration a roll back should happen", I have the code bellow:

```
@Transactional(rollbackOn = {BadRequestException.class})
    public Response register(UserDTO userDTO, Tenant tenant, Channel channel) {


        String username = userDTO.getFirstName() + "_" + userDTO.getLastName() + Helper.generateCode();
        userDTO.setUserName(username.toLowerCase());
        String phone = userDTO.getCountryCode() + Helper.removeLeadingZeros(userDTO.getPhone());
        List<Role> roles = List.of(Role.valueOf(tenant.getTenant().toUpperCase()), Role.valueOf(tenant.getType().toUpperCase()));
        var response = keycloakService.createKeycloakUser(userDTO, roles, Collections.singletonMap("gsm", List.of(phone)));
        var userId = CreatedResponseUtil.getCreatedId(response);


        // store the user in sys local db
        UserLoginData sys_user = loginDataMapper.toEntity(userDTO);
        sys_user.setKeycloakId(UUID.fromString(Objects.requireNonNull(userId)));
        sys_user.setPhone(phone);
        userLoginService.saveAndPublishEvent(sys_user);
        log.info("A new user has been add to Sys DB");

        if (channel == Channel.none)
            return response;

        if (channel == Channel.phone)
            twilioService.sendOTP(phone);
        else
            sendVerificationMail(userDTO.getEmailId());

        return response;
    }
```

and this is the  code for creating the user on keycloak:

```
@SneakyThrows
    public Response createKeycloakUser(UserDTO userDto, List<Role> roles, Map<String, List<String>> attributes) {
        CredentialRepresentation credential = Credentials.createPasswordCredentials(userDto.getPassword());
        UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
        user.setFirstName(userDto.getFirstName());
        user.setEmail(userDto.getEmailId());
        user.setLastName(userDto.getLastName());
        user.setUsername(userDto.getUserName());
        user.setAttributes(attributes);
        user.setCredentials(Collections.singletonList(credential));


        var realmResource = getRealmResource();

        //check if this phone already registered
        var alreadyExist = getUserByPhoneNum(attributes.get("gsm").get(0));
        if (alreadyExist != null) {
            throw new UserAlreadyExistedException();
        }

        var response = realmResource.users().create(user);

        var userId = CreatedResponseUtil.getCreatedId(response);
        var userResource = realmResource.users().get(userId);

        ClientRepresentation clientRepresentation = realmResource.clients().findAll()
                .stream().filter(client -> client.getClientId().equals(keyCloakConfig.getResource())).collect(Collectors.toList())
                .get(0);
        ClientResource clientResource = realmResource.clients().get(clientRepresentation.getId());

        //get the client roles that map the roles in passed array
        List<RoleRepresentation> clientRole = clientResource.roles().list()
                .stream().filter(roleRepresentation ->
                        roles.stream().anyMatch(r -> r.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(roleRepresentation.getName())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());


        //assign the user to a group


        userResource.roles()
                .clientLevel(clientRepresentation.getId())
                .add(clientRole);//Collections.singletonList(clientRole));

//        log.info("Role {}  has been assigned to user with the id: {} ", role.getValue(), userId);

        return response;

    }
```

how can I make the the registration at keycloak transactional?? thanks in advance;

Comment: I doubt you can, as it is http (afaik) and http isn't transactional. The only thing you can do (maybe) is to compensate for the error and manually remove the entries (with manually I mean create a service which does this and which you call upon the error).

Comment: mmm, right you have a point, I thought about this but I wanted to be sure, as you mentioned http is not transactional, probably i'll go with manual solution, thx a lot , I will keep the question open in case there is any better one